# Selenium chromedriver svg dom grab links

Tags: selenium, dom, svg, selenium-chromedriver

I have this `http://app.risorseumane.uniparthenope.it/organigramma/organigramma.htm`
web page where i need to get all the links from the web page. For example i want the link

```
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.uniparthenope.it/ateneo/organigramma/rettore" target="_top">
            <g id="shape48-47" transform="translate(355,-400.951)">
                <title>Entità esterna 1.48</title>
                <desc>Rettore</desc>
                <g id="shadow48-48" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,2.12132,2.12132)" class="st5">
                    <rect x="0" y="531.345" width="136.459" height="63.9306" class="st6"/>
                </g>
                <rect x="0" y="531.345" width="136.459" height="63.9306" class="st7"/>
                <text x="48.7" y="566.91" class="st8">Rettore</text>            </g>
        </a>
```

which i can only see using the "Inspect element" function of chrome or by calling `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` in the developer tools window in chrome.

Unfortunatly i can't get these links using `driver.findElementsByTagName("a");`
or using

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = null;
                        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
                            js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                        }
List<Object> fsLinks = (List<Object>)js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('a');");
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't get them? What happens? Update your question with the details.

Comment: There are only two links in that site?!

Comment: @MosheSlavin the page has more then 2 links.

Comment: Not in the format you shown...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with xpath:

> //*[name() = 'a']

or

> //*[local-name() = 'a']

Comment: Nah not working by the way i have found the solution, i'll post it later.